# Convert less into Sass function, variables problems

Tags: sass, less

I am trying to convert a less function into Sass, but it doesn't work

LESS:

```
@iconNb : 35;
    @espaces : @iconNb * 2; 
    @iconSpriteBackgroundSize : @espaces * 100%;
    .svg(@index, @y:0){
        background-size:@iconSpriteBackgroundSize;
        @x :  -(@index * 100%);
        background-position : @x @y !important;;
    }
```

Sass:

```
 @mixin svg($index){
    $iconNb : 35;
    $espaces : $iconNb * 2; 
    background-size: $espaces * 100%;
    $x :  -($index * 100%);
    background-position : $x 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this website can help you about it; http://csspre.com/convert/

Comment: works for me [Less](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40iconNb%20%3A%2035%3B%5Cn%40espaces%20%3A%20%40iconNb%20*%202%3B%20%5Cn%40iconSpriteBackgroundSize%20%3A%20%40espaces%20*%20100%25%3B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20.svg(%40index%2C%20%40y%3A0)%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background-size%3A%40iconSpriteBackgroundSize%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40x%20%3A%20%20-(%40index%20*%20100%25)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background-position%20%3A%20%40x%20%40y%20!important%3B%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%5Cn.example%7B%5Cn.svg(3)%5Cn%7D%22%7D) ...

Comment: and [SASS](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/311fbaf7ee8353f6ab0ade4d0f91f74f)

Comment: no the background position $x is wrong , I dont get the same number with SASS and LESS

Comment: Show an example

Comment: sorry now it works!

thanks to all

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-scss-convertor